# how to set variable value in pattern regex in Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

how to set variable value in pattern regx in Jquery.I want to set pattern value dyanamically.Please help me How to set

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <script language="javascript">
      function checkABC(str){
    var test="abc";
        var pattern = /'test'/gi
        if(str.match(pattern)){
          alert('matches');
        }else{
          alert('no match');
        }
      }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="matches" onclick="checkABC('deabcfg')" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor

```
function checkABC(str) {
    var test = "abc";
    var pattern = new RegExp(test, 'gi');
    if (str.match(pattern)) {
        alert('matches');
    } else {
        alert('no match');
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Uquqx/)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
var pattern = new RegExp("regex"+test,"g");
```